# select all paragraphs except first and last one inside div using xpath query

Tags: xpath

i want to select all paragraphs inside div element except first and last paragraph

e.g code

> Blockquote

first content

second one

third one

four one

data

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your code sample, but you can select all paragraphs except the first and last like this:

```
/div/p[position() gt 1 and position() lt last()]
```

Comment: <div id="article">
<p>test</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>ha</p>
<p class="last_one">content again</p>
</div>
a sample code i try yours and not working with it's gimme error in parsing

Comment: i tested @joemfb code against your input XML and it shows `<p>content</p>`
`<p>ha</p>`

Comment: What was the parse error? What XPath processor are you using?